# Python: While loop problem with input function in tic-tac-toe game

Tags: python, while-loop, tic-tac-toe

I'm on my first Python project trying to create a tic-tac-toe game. I have a question regarding while loop logic. So I have a player input function, whereby the player decides what marker (X or O) in tic-tac-toe they would like to play with.

My function is as follows:

```py
def player_input():
    marker = ''
    
    while marker != 'X' or  marker != 'O':
        marker = input('Player 1 choose X or O ').upper()
        
    if marker == 'X':
        return ('X','O')
    else:
        return ('O','X')
```

The result is the while loop continues to ask the user the question even if they give the correct input `('X' or 'O')`

However, upon checking the solution, this modification to the while loop statement returns the tuple corresponding to the marker the user entered:

```py
while not (marker == 'X' or marker == 'O'):
```

I don't understand how this works, From my perspective I have written the exact same thing above in the `player_input` function, am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: `while marker != 'X' or  marker != 'O':` -> `while marker != 'X'  and marker != 'O':` If it's 'X' then it's not 'O', and vice versa, so the `or` condition is always met

Comment: `not (A or B)` is equivalent to `(not A) and (not B)`, negation is not distributive over conjunction or disjunction.

Answer (score 1):

Your Logic will never leave the while statement as both truth statements, `marker != 'X'` and `marker != 'O'`, cannot be both False at the same time. If you entered `'x' or 'X'` the marker `marker != 'O'` statement would be True and vice versa, causing the while loop to repeat.

You could instead use `while marker != 'X' and  marker != 'O':`, which will move on when your input is either `X` or `O`.

Answer (score -1):

We can try every case scenario to understand the case.

**Let's say user type a.**

```
marker != 'O' or marker != 'X'
```

Both expressions, right and left will be true since marker is different than O and X. True or True = True. The loop continue.

**Let's say user type X.**

```
marker != 'X' or marker != 'O'
```

The first expression will be true, the second false. True or False = True
Your while loop will keep going asking.

**Let's say user type O.**

```
 marker != 'X' or marker != 'O'
```

The second expression will be True, the first false. False or True = True
The loop will keep going.

The only way to stop the loop is for marker to be X and O at the same time. Both expression would evaluation to False. False or False = False. But it is impossible in your case. When you use !=, the expression is True when marker is different than X or O. It is False when it is equal. See the picture for a summary of boolean logic. It's always nice to have one next to you to remember. After a while, it becomes natural.

[image]